# No wireless networks found - BackTrack 5 - Wicd Network Manager - VmWare

Tags: vmware, backtrack

I have a Lenovo T500 laptop with an Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
I have Win 7 Enterprise installed as the OS
Inside that Win 7 install, I have installed VmWare Workstation (8.0.0 build-471780)
Inside the VmWare, I have installed BackTrack 5 (BT5r1-GNOME-64)
Under the VmWare settings, I have Bridged Mode Enabled for the Network Adapter
In BT5r1-GNOME-64, under the Wicd Network Manager, it says "No wireless networks found"

What do I fix so that it can find the wireless networks?

Is the issue with BackTrack, VmWare, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You laptop's built-in wireless network will appear as a plain ethernet adapter in BT.

You can type `dhclient`in a BT terminal to get a new DHCP address if needed.

If you are looking to do packet-injection, then you will most likely need an external USB wifi card that is capable of doing packet-injection (google around for this). When you plug in the usb wifi, you will be prompted on whether you want to use this card with your host operating system or if you want to pass it through to vmWare.

Comment: Well that is a bummer...Can you explain this line a bit more: "You laptop's built-in wireless network will appear as a plain ethernet adapter in BT."
Why does it work that way?  Is this a driver issue?  Is there anything that can be done about that, besides buying a USB wifi card?